# A class of sets "picking out" a set

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

The idea of sets being shattered comes up a lot in statistical learning theory with applications to VC dimension. Before learning about this, I am trying to understand the following definition.

> Let $F=\left \{ x_{1}, x_{2},...,x_{n} \right \}$ be a finite set.  Let $G$ be a subset of $F$.  We say that a class of sets $\mathcal{A}$ $\textbf{picks out}$ $G$ if 
>   $$A \cap F = G$$
>   for some set $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

The author then gives the following example:

> Consider the class of sets $\mathcal{A} =\left \{ (a,b): a \leq b \right \}$.  Suppose that $F=\left \{ 1,2,7,8,9 \right \}$ and $G = \left \{ 2,7 \right \}.$  Then $\mathcal{A}$ picks out $G$ since $A \cap F = G$, if we take $A= \left \{ 1.5,7.5 \right \}$ for example.

Clearly, looking at this example, 
$$A \cap F = \emptyset \neq G.$$
So, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like an obvious typo, doesn't it? $A$ was supposed to be an element of $\mathcal A$, so I guess $A=\{1.5,7.5\}$ was supposed to read $A=(1.5,7.5)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the definition of each element of the class of sets is $\left(a,b\right)$ such that $a \le b$, for some given $a$ and $b$. As such, $A = \left\{1.5,7.5\right\}$ is the set of all real numbers between $a = 1.5$ and $b = 7.5$, which of course includes $2$ and $7$, but no other element of $F$, so it's intersection with $F$ is just the elements of $G$, as stated.

**Update**: I don't really know much about set theory, but I would have thought a better way to express $A$ would be something like $A = \left(1.5,7.5\right)$ (as [bof](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111012/bof) suggests in a question comment), or perhaps something like $A = \left\{x : 1.5 \lt x \lt 7.5\right\}$. Otherwise, as currently expressed, it seems to be a set with just $2$ elements, i.e., $1.5$ and $7.5$, which is why the OP is asking this question. It is likely just be a typo in the book.

Comment: Thanks!  It took me a while but I finally understand it.

Comment: @MathIsLife12 You are welcome. When I first read your question, I was also confused like you. However, on rereading the definition for the class of sets, $\mathcal{A}$, I only then recognized what was apparently going on.